# Не получается добавить новую строку в QTableWidget по нажатию на кнопку в другом окне

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Есть три модуля:

- **primary_window.py** - сгенерирован *Qt Designer*, в нем расположена таблица `QTableWidget`
- **secondary_window.py** - сгенерирован *Qt Designer*, в нем есть кнопка и поля `QLineEdit` для внесения данных.
- **main_test.py** - собственно здесь прописываю всю логику взаимодействия.

Цель - заполнить таблицу `QTableWidget` в `primary_window` по внесенным вручную данным в окне `secondary_window` и после нажатия на кнопку `pushButton_Save`.

Начал с меньшего - чтобы при нажатии на кнопку добавлялась строка с произвольными данными, но это не получается сделать.

**main_test.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from secondary_window import Ui_Dialog
from primary_window import Ui_MainWindow

class primary_window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(primary_window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui_main = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui_main.setupUi(self)
        self.ui_main.pushButton_addItem.clicked.connect(self.show_secondary_window)
        #self.ui_main.pushButton_addItem.clicked.connect(self.add_new_item)    When uncomment this and comment previous line - new line in tabWidget is added

    def show_secondary_window(self):
        self.ui_sec = secondary_window()
        self.ui_sec.show()

    def add_new_item(self, value):
        print(value)
        row_position = self.ui_main.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.insertRow(row_position) #this doesn't work when calling add_new_item from secondary_window
        print('here')
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(row_position, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("text1"))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(row_position, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("text2"))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(row_position, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("text3"))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(row_position, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("text4"))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(row_position, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("text5"))
        print('inserted')


class secondary_window(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(secondary_window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui_sec = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui_sec.setupUi(self)
        self.ui_sec.pushButton_Save.clicked.connect(self.close_secondary_window_and_save_new_item)

    def close_secondary_window_and_save_new_item(self):
        value = 'I\'m just a random value to be passed to the add_new_item'
        self.close()
        primary_window().add_new_item(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = primary_window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**primary_window.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 4, item)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.pushButton_addItem = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_addItem.setObjectName("pushButton_addItem")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_addItem)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "q"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "w"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "r"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "t"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "22"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "234"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "32"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "23"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "33"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "22"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "421"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2432"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "324"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "23"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.pushButton_addItem.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add Item"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**secondary_window.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 204)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.qLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.qLabel.setObjectName("qLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.qLabel)
        self.qLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.qLineEdit.setObjectName("qLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.qLineEdit)
        self.wLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.wLabel.setObjectName("wLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.wLabel)
        self.wLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.wLineEdit.setObjectName("wLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.wLineEdit)
        self.eLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.eLabel.setObjectName("eLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.eLabel)
        self.eLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.eLineEdit.setObjectName("eLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.eLineEdit)
        self.rLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.rLabel.setObjectName("rLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.rLabel)
        self.rLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.rLineEdit.setObjectName("rLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.rLineEdit)
        self.tLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.tLabel.setObjectName("tLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.tLabel)
        self.tLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.tLineEdit.setObjectName("tLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.tLineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout)
        self.pushButton_Save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_Save.setObjectName("pushButton_Save")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Save)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.qLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "q"))
        self.wLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "w"))
        self.eLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "e"))
        self.rLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "r"))
        self.tLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "t"))
        self.pushButton_Save.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Save"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

При вызове метода add_new_item из primary_window - проблем нет, строка добавляется
А вот при вызове метода add_new_item из secondary_window - нет, хотя принты проходят и приложение не крашится.
Не могу понять в чем проблема и как ее исправить.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь и пояснения!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я отметил для вас изменения, которые вам надо сделать. Если что-то не понятно - спросите.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from secondary_window import Ui_Dialog
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 204)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.qLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.qLabel.setObjectName("qLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.qLabel)
        self.qLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.qLineEdit.setObjectName("qLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.qLineEdit)
        self.wLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.wLabel.setObjectName("wLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.wLabel)
        self.wLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.wLineEdit.setObjectName("wLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.wLineEdit)
        self.eLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.eLabel.setObjectName("eLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.eLabel)
        self.eLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.eLineEdit.setObjectName("eLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.eLineEdit)
        self.rLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.rLabel.setObjectName("rLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.rLabel)
        self.rLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.rLineEdit.setObjectName("rLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.rLineEdit)
        self.tLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.tLabel.setObjectName("tLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.tLabel)
        self.tLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.tLineEdit.setObjectName("tLineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.tLineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout)
        self.pushButton_Save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_Save.setObjectName("pushButton_Save")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Save)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.qLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "q"))
        self.wLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "w"))
        self.eLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "e"))
        self.rLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "r"))
        self.tLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "t"))
        self.pushButton_Save.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Save"))
        
        
#from primary_window import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 4, item)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.pushButton_addItem = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_addItem.setObjectName("pushButton_addItem")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_addItem)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "q"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "w"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "r"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "t"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "22"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "234"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "32"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "23"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "33"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "22"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "421"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2432"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "324"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "23"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.pushButton_addItem.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add Item"))
        
        
class PrimaryWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PrimaryWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.ui_main = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui_main.setupUi(self)
        self.ui_main.pushButton_addItem.clicked.connect(self.show_secondary_window)

    def show_secondary_window(self):
        self.ui_sec = SecondaryWindow(self)                            # +++  self 
        self.ui_sec.open()                                # - show()     + open() или exec()

    def add_new_item(self, values):
        row_position = self.ui_main.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.insertRow(row_position) #this doesn't work when calling add_new_item from secondary_window

        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[0].text()))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[1].text()))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[2].text()))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[3].text()))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[4].text()))
        print('inserted')


class SecondaryWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondaryWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent                                        # +++ self.parent
        
        self.ui_sec = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui_sec.setupUi(self)
        self.ui_sec.pushButton_Save.clicked.connect(self.close_secondary_window_and_save_new_item)

    def close_secondary_window_and_save_new_item(self):
        value = 'I\'m just a random value to be passed to the add_new_item'
        self.close()
        
        values = self.findChildren(QLineEdit)                # +++
#        for item in values:
#            print(f'{item.text()}') #
        
# ???
#        PrimaryWindow().add_new_item(value)                 # !!! вот так делать не надо
        self.parent.add_new_item(values)                     # +++ self.parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PrimaryWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**:

> 1. Если правильно понял, если захочу использовать несколько ComboBox'ов взамен нескольких LineEdit - нужно дополнительно использовать `.findChildren(QComboBox)`, собрать список/кортеж текстовых значений из результатов и уже его передавать.
> 2. Если правильно понимаю: **`parent`** - ссылка на родительский класс и работает даже тогда, когда имя родительского класса изменилось. Но почему в конкретном случае, когда имя родителя не меняется, не будет работать вызов `PrimaryWindow.add_new_item(values)` ?

1. Да, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren
2. Вам надо освежить знания **`ООП`**:

- создаем объект/экземпляр `w = PrimaryWindow()` и показываем его `w.show()`.
  Это ваше главное окно. См. `print(f'111   - {w}')`
- смотрите принты в методе `show_secondary_window(self)`,
  где мы создаем объект диалогового окна:

  ```
    print(f'\n222 1 - {self.ui_sec.parent}') 
    print(f'222 2 - {self}')
  ```
- всякий раз когда вы пишите `PrimaryWindow()` - вы создаете
  **НОВЫЙ** объект/экземпляр, который вы в дальнейшем нигде не используете.
- итого: есть класс, создаем (**`один раз`**) его экземпляр и дальше
  с этим объектом/экземпляром работаем.

---

```
...

        
class PrimaryWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PrimaryWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.ui_main = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui_main.setupUi(self)
        self.ui_main.pushButton_addItem.clicked.connect(self.show_secondary_window)

    def show_secondary_window(self):
        self.ui_sec = SecondaryWindow(self)                            # +++  self 
        print(f'\n222 1 - {self.ui_sec.parent}') 
        print(f'222 2 - {self}') 
        
        self.ui_sec.open()                                # - show()     + open() или exec()

    def add_new_item(self, values):
        row_position = self.ui_main.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.insertRow(row_position) #this doesn't work when calling add_new_item from secondary_window

        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[0].text()))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[1].text()))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[2].text()))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[3].text()))
        self.ui_main.tableWidget.setItem(
            row_position, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(values[4].text()))
        print('inserted')


class SecondaryWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondaryWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent                                        # +++ self.parent
        
        self.ui_sec = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui_sec.setupUi(self)
        self.ui_sec.pushButton_Save.clicked.connect(self.close_secondary_window_and_save_new_item)

    def close_secondary_window_and_save_new_item(self):
        value = 'I\'m just a random value to be passed to the add_new_item'
        self.close()
        
        values = self.findChildren(QLineEdit)                # +++
#        for item in values:
#            print(f'{item.text()}') #
 
        print(f'\n333   - {PrimaryWindow()}') # 
# ???
#        PrimaryWindow().add_new_item(value)                 # !!! вот так делать не надо
        self.parent.add_new_item(values)                     # +++ self.parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PrimaryWindow()
    print(f'111   - {w}') 
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо! 1. Если правильно понял, если захочу использовать несколько ComboBox'ов взамен нескольких LineEdit  - нужно дополнительно использовать .findChildren(QComboBox), собрать список/кортеж текстовых значений из результатов и уже его передавать.   2. Если правильно понимаю: parent - ссылка на родительский класс и работает даже тогда,  когда имя родительского класса изменилось. Но почему в конкретном случае, когда имя родителя не меняется, не будет работать вызов PrimaryWindow.add_new_item(values) ?

Comment: @ВадимМаслов пожалуйста, я добавил обновления в свой ответ - проверьте.